# Batch "input line is too long" while calling csc.exe from bat script

Tags: windows, batch-file, dll, cmd, csc

My code attempts to make csc.exe reference all .dll files from the /DLLs directory.

```
@echo on
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
del Assembly.dll
cd DLLs
set "imports="
for /r %%i in ("*.dll") do set "imports=!imports!,%%i"
set "imports=%imports:~1%"
cd ..
csc.exe -nostdlib -target:library -out:Assembly.dll Loader.cs MainScript.cs -r:%imports%
```

However, if I have too many .dlls in the directory, the last line gives me an "input line is too long" error due to cmd.exe not being able to handle that many characters. Do you have any workarounds/solutions for this problem?

Comment: Please try the command `csc.exe /?` and see if the `@<file>` might work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/response-file-compiler-option

Comment: I don't see a `-r` argument for [csc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe)

Comment: Your `for in do` can be reduced to: `for /r %%i in ("*.dll") do set "imports=imports,%%i"` unless you just plain wrote it wrong.  If you reduce it you do not need delayedexpansion.  I get the same results using this code or yours.

Comment: @somebadhat: `set "imports=imports,%%i"` and `set "imports=!imports!,%%i"` is a *huge*  difference.

Comment: @somebadhat **-r** is the short form of [**-reference**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/reference-compiler-option#remarks).

Comment: powershell doesn't have the character limit that cmd.exe has. What about dir /x?

Comment: @somebadhat I don't know the specific character limit details but older versions of Windows don't have PowerShell as part of its installation only CMD.

Comment: what version Windows? 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: Would putting an example of what `-r:%imports%` is supposed to look like help?  Put it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58859596/batch-input-line-is-too-long-while-calling-csc-exe-from-bat-script#comment103995350_58859596) you should use the [@ compiler option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/response-file-compiler-option) that links to a `.rsp` file where you store the compiler options including the references.

The file looks like the `csc.rsp` (in the same folder as `csc.exe`) which is part of every compilation unless the [-noconfig compiler option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/noconfig-compiler-option) is specified.

Example `references.rsp`:

```
-r:Microsoft.CSharp.dll
-r:System.Core.dll
-r:System.dll
-r:System.Windows.Forms.Dll
```

You can create the file programmatically in your batch file.